# Does "where" works with mutattors in eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a mutattor in an eloquent model that generates a "status" atribute.

```
public function getStatusAttribute(){

 if(){
      return "enabled";
 }
          else 
    {
      return "disabled";
  }



}
```

Can I use?

```
   $query = Anuncio::query();

       $query->where('status', "enabled" );


    return $query->get();
```

I seems that I cannot. I getting "status" column not defined. How can I get around this problem?

Comment: You can't. Use query scopes instead

Answer (score 0):

No doesn't works it works on model level 
you can use after query from database in collection result

Answer (score 0):

No, when you are doing a query you are asking the database, therefor there needs to be a column status.

There is a way, retrieve x elements from the database and use the Laravel Collection method `where()`. This is not optimal if you have many elements in teh database, it will retrieve all of them.

```
Anuncio::all()->where('status', 'enabled')->all();
```